# UILabels text disappears when animating

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
- (void)my_button_tapped
{
if (my_button.tag == 0)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    my_label.frame = CGRectMake(450, 455, 200, 20);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [my_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    my_button.tag = 1;
}
else
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    my_label.frame = CGRectMake(450, 455, 0, 20);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [my_button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    my_button.tag = 0;
}
}
```

When I tap my_button first time the label is expanded into 200px width, when I press the button again the label decreases to 0px width but immediately at button press the text disappears. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the button knows that at the end of the animation the text won't be able to be displayed (due to the width) and so it hides the text label.  To get the effect you want you probably want to use a `CGAffineTransform` scale to compress it to zero width.

Comment: How exactly is that used?

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen you'll want to use `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 1)`.  That returns a CGAffineTransform that you set on the labels `.transform` property.  There shouldn't be any problem setting that as part of your animations.